# Stripe API: Attach uploaded file (ex PDF) to an object (ex Customers, Products, etc...)?

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe API has a way of uploading files, and its response is file object's `"file_id"`:
https://stripe.com/docs/file-upload

```
curl https://files.stripe.com/v1/files \
  -u sk_test_***:*** \
  -F "file"="@/path/to/a/file.jpg" \
  -F "purpose"="dispute_evidence"
```

I aim to attach (aka associate, reference) an uploaded file by its `"file_id"` to another object (e.g., customer, product, subscription...).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

That’s not really the intended purpose of Stripe’s files API - see file.purpose :
https://stripe.com/docs/api/files/object#file_object-purpose

That said, you can just set the file_id as a metadata value on any object you want.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata

Answer (score 2):

File ID's are expected only in specific fields of some API requests, such as several kinds of dispute evidence:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/disputes/update#update_dispute-evidence-receipt

> evidence.receipt optional
> (ID of a file upload) Any receipt or message sent to the customer notifying them of the charge.

or various kinds of identity verification for Accounts:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-documents-bank_account_ownership_verification-files

> documents.bank_account_ownership_verification.files optional
> One or more document ids returned by a file upload with a purpose value of account_requirement.

But as @Lucky2501 mentioned, theoretically you *could* record a file id on any object's `metadata`